# jqGrid is stretching row height to fit grid height

Tags: jqgrid

It appears that when jqGrid has only a few rows, it increases the height of the rows to fill the available space. Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Comment: I never faced such a situation. can you include the code for your jqgrid?

Answer (score 1):

I know it is very old question but if anyone has this problem 
remove  height attribute from table if specified in css.

for Ex.

```
<div id="divGrid">
        <table id="tbl" style="height:350px;overflow-y:auto;"></table>
        <div id="tblPager"></div>
</div>
```

change to

```
 <div id="divGrid">
        <table id="tbl"></table>
        <div id="tblPager"></div>
 </div>
```

to make fix height of jqgrid please use height option of jqGrid 
documentation can be find on http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options

Answer (score 0):

Probably you use `height: "auto"` or `height: "100%"` option of jqGrid. You can use any numeric value to specify the height of the grid in pixel. By the way the default value of the `height` parameter is 150 (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions)).

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that after some investigation, there was a style applied higher up that somebody had been using to try to set the size of the grid even though we were also setting it in code. That was somehow trickling down to the row height. I'm still not sure how it happened, since F12 tools couldn't see anything.

I guess the recommendation from this is to not rely on CSS to set the size. The grid size must be set in JavaScript.